# How to check $_GET isset for a parameter and value?

Tags: php

Let's say I have a link:

https://www.example.com/?name=john

I know how to do something if a specific parameter exists :

```php
<?php if (isset($_GET['name'])) : ?>
```

What I want is to use `if` for both, parameter and value.

Basically I want to do like this:

```php
<?php if (isset($_GET['name, john'])) : ?>
```

Above is just an example. It's doesn't work.

Can anyone guide to the right code for this?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.  The first example you give is how you check if the parameter exists at all.  If it exists, it has a value.  What are you trying to find out about that value?

Comment: Check for the existance _and_ the value: `if(isset($_GET['name']) && $_GET['name'] == 'john') :`

Comment: Thanks brombeer! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to check if the parameter is set and after that if parameter equals the expected value.

Like this:

```php
<?php if (isset($_GET['name'])) : ?>
    <?php if ($_GET['name'] === 'john') : ?>
        // Name exists and is john
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```